# Expectation of gradients

Tags: optimization, expected-value, gradient

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0030v2.pdf) and am puzzled by equation 8. I don't understand the last bit: why can we move the gradient out of the expectation? $$E_Q[\nabla_\phi\log Q_\phi(h|x)] = E_Q[\frac{\nabla_\phi Q_\phi(h|x)}{Q_\phi(h|x)}]=\nabla_\phi E_Q[1]=0.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ E_Q\left[\frac{\nabla_\phi Q_\phi(h|x)}{Q_\phi(h|x)}\right] = \int\frac{\nabla_\phi Q_\phi(h|x)}{Q_\phi(h|x)} Q_\phi(h|x) = \int{\nabla_\phi Q_\phi(h|x)}$$

Assuming that you can [exchange the integral and the gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) operators (deep waters)

$$  = \nabla_\phi\int{ Q_\phi(h|x)} = \nabla_\phi E_Q[1] = \nabla_\phi 1 =0$$

Since the distribution $Q$ is chosen by the user, you can say that this result is satisfied by those $Q$ that allow exchanging the integral and the gradient.